# how to know how many memory resources I'm using with sessionState variables

Tags: asp.net, memory, resources, session-state

It's possible to know how many memory resources I'm using with SessionState variables in an Asp.Net site? I don't want to make changes to the application to resolve it. Will be great if I can know this using some tool or the IIS.

I'm planing to move the sessionState from InProc to Sql, but I need to know first how big is the problem I have.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077780/how-can-i-determine-the-memory-footprint-of-a-session-variable), there is no way to know how much memory is being used by session. But you can make a guess (see also that question I linked and the answer from Mark Schupp [here](http://thedailyreviewer.com/server/view/how-can-a-measure-server-session-memory-usage-108308535)):

> For each session variable:
>     2* the number of chars in the name
>     + 8 bytes overhead
>     + Data size
>   Remember that strings are stored internally as unicode (2 bytes/char).

Comment: Yes, but I can do this only if I write code into the application. If there any way to do this outside the site?

Comment: In the post you are talking about, I think I found the answer: You could change your backing store to SQL Server and look at the size of SessionItemShort or SessionItemLong to get an idea of what the serialized size of the data is. Probably not exact, but should be close.

Comment: @Ariel Larraburu: Yes, this is a possibility. I just didn't want to quote all answers from that question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
foreach(var obj in Session) {
  bf.Serialize(m, obj);
}

long bytes = m.Length; // real size
```

Comment: to enable code highligter add four spaces before each line of code

Comment: Doing this I can get the session size, but I need to know the size of all the session variables on the site.

Comment: Session variables are stored in a SessionStateItemCollection object that is exposed through the HttpContext.Session property. In an ASP.NET page, the current session variables are exposed through the Session property of the Page object.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own, and check amount of data in session state. By it is hard way... Details [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/StateHijack.aspx?display=Print).

Comment: it seems pretty interesting, but is too hard to apply to the site.